# How to show the trace inequality of two P.S.D matrices $\text{Tr(X)}\leq\text{Tr(Y)}$ when $X \preceq Y$?

Tags: matrices, inequality, positive-definite

Let $X,Y$ be two Positive Semi-Definite matrices. How can we show the following in the most elegant and shortest way? Because I know how to prove it but I think there is a better way?
Alos, [MaoWao](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3074592/how-to-show-texttrab-leq-texttrac-where-b-preceq-c) shows it differently using summation.

$$\text{Tr}(X)\leq\text{Tr}(Y)$$ when $X \preceq Y$, where $Y-X$ is positive semi-definite?

My try is:

$x^T(Y-X)x \geq 0$ so $\text{Tr}(xx^T(Y-X)) \geq 0$.

Then using [$\text{tr}(AB) \leq \text{tr(A)} \text{tr(B)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3061871/what-are-the-conditions-on-texttrab-leq-texttra-texttrb-to-be)

$$0 \leq \text{Tr}(xx^T(Y-X)) \leq \text{Tr}(xx^T)\text{Tr}(Y-X)$$
hence the claim.

I do not want to use this $\text{tr}(AB) \leq \text{tr(A)} \text{tr(B)}$ or sumation. Is there any other way to show it shorter?

Comment: What does $X \preceq Y$ mean? That $Y-X$ is positive semidefinite?

Comment: @ Lord Shark the Unknown: Yes

Comment: Then each diagonal entry in $Y-X$ is nonnegative.

Comment: @ Lord Shark the Unknown: You are right. Then to get the inequality we need use this fact and sum over the diagonals to get the result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $e_i$ be a the basis vector with 1 in element $i$, and 0's elsewhere. Then
\begin{align*}
e_i^\intercal (Y - X) e_i = Y_{ii} - X_{ii} \ge 0
\end{align*}
Summing over $i$,
\begin{align*}
\text{tr}(Y-X) = \sum_i(Y_{ii} - X_{ii}) \ge 0
\end{align*}

Comment: still using summation! This is exactly what is in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3074592/how-to-show-texttrab-leq-texttrac-where-b-preceq-c which I said. Can you show it without summation?

Comment: Ah, that may be very difficult. The trace itself, by definition, is a sum, and any direct proof I can imagine (avoiding eigenvalues, for example), would involve quadratic forms which, in itself, are sums (of squares).

Answer (score 1):

Since $Y - X$ is positive semidefinite, all its eigenvalues are nonnegative, so $Tr(Y-X) \geq 0$.  Now, by linearity of the trace operator, $Tr(Y) - Tr(X) \geq 0.$

Comment: The question is why all eigenvalues are nonnegative $\text{Tr}(Y-X)\leq 0$. Please read the statement carefully and confer to the provided links.

Comment: Sorry, I took it as the definition of positive semidefinite that all the eigenvalues are nonnegative (this is often the case).

Comment: @Saeed: Please delete the answer because it does not follow the statement. The problem is not as easy as it seems. Or you can provide a good answer.

Comment: What is your definition of positive semidefinite?  Is it that $x^* A x \geq 0$ for all vectors $x \neq 0$?  If so, because $A$ is Hermitian, then it is unitarily diagonalizable.  Hence, by a change of variables, if $A = UDU^*$, where $U$ is unitary and $D$ is diagonal.  Then $0 \leq x^* A x = (Ux)^* D Ux = y^* D y$ for all vectors $y \neq 0$ (since unitary matrices are bijective).  Hence, taking $y$ to be a standard basis vector gives that each entry of $D$ is nonnegative, or that the eigenvalues of $A$ are nonnegative. So my definition and yours are equivalent.